# session::push error htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

Tags: php, session, laravel-5

I insert a number of items in a session using `session::push` it works till refreshing page I get error:

> htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string

Here is the controller function:

```
 public function shopping(Request $request){
    if($request->has('cart')){

        $x=request('name');
        $y=request('quantity');
        Session::push('item',$x);

        return view('Crochet.shopping');

    } else {
        return redirect()->back();
    }
}
```

in view:

```
@foreach(session('item')as $y){{$y}} @endforeach
```

How can it be fixed?

*Added from comments:*

the `$x` is a string I request from the url in each page:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/Pearl%20Crochet/cart/shopping?name=Nubian&image=image1.jpg
```

`$x` is the name.

Comment: Can you show me the content of $x? I want to know the datatype

Comment: sure the $x is a string I request from the url ineach page http://127.0.0.1:8000/Pearl%20Crochet/cart/shopping?name=Nubian&image=image1.jpg                                                             $x is the name ..could it be the error?

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the session exists before the loop:

```
@if (session('item'))

   @foreach(session('item') as $y)
     {{ $y }} 
   @endforeach

@endif
```